# How to make an object move along a Grease Pencil curved line?

Tags: grease-pencil

I need an object that will move along a Grease Pencil curve to use it for procedural weight generation.

Comment: why don't you use an ordinary (not visible) curve?

Comment: If you already have a grease pencil object, you can duplicate it, convert to curve and then add a constraint `Follow Path` to the object.